# Cannot execute new installed program

Tags: 12.04, opera, installed-programs

My ubuntu is 12.04LTS

I was used apt-get to install `opera` and `cowsay`. I've tried to execute them, but they all said

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cowsay
bash: /usr/games/cowsay: Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ opera-next
bash: /usr/bin/opera-next: Permission denied
```

I've already tried `chmod a+x` them but they won't work

Here is mount output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1017476k,nr_inodes=214672,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=410052k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/.filesystems/usr/usr.sqfs on /.filesystems/usr/squash type squashfs (ro,relatime)
aufs on /usr type aufs (rw,relatime,si=f8757c62)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
```

And `ls -l` of these 2 file

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /usr/games/cowsay
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4421 Dec 22  2010 /usr/games/cowsay
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/opera-next
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 169 Jan 17 22:44 /usr/bin/opera-next
```

And `cat` of those file

http://pastebin.com/FP3MiQ6t (They are to long so I post them here)

Comment: Could you show us a "ls -l" from these two files?

Comment: @jap1968 `ls -l` info added

Comment: are these scripts launching other commands? I mean, can you use "cat" to see their contents or they are compiled executable files?

Comment: Does this work: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/games/cowsay`

Comment: @jap1968: cowsay is perl scripts and opera-next is a shell scripts.

Comment: So, maybe the problem is not on the script itself, but in the commands the script tries to invoke?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker It's not work

Comment: @jap1968 I've tried to execute the file that opera-next tried to execute. But that one also say: Permission denied. `ls -l` show that file also executable too

Comment: Hmm, can you execute the programs as root (`sudo cowsay moo`)?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker I've tried. The results still the same: Permission Denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's beacuse of aufs mount of /usr I've used squashfs /usr speedup method. I was fixed it by change fstab aufs entry like this

```
overlayfs /usr overlayfs noatime,nodiratime,lowerdir=//.filesystems/usr/squash,upperdir=/.filesystems/usr/overlay
```

Hope this help with anybody face my problem

Answer (score 0):

well actually its not going to work in that way.

you need to enter that file name.actually cowsay can have arguments.

for example loot at the image I have attached

[image]

And I think you'd better move with its [man-page.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cowsay)

> Cowsay generates an ASCII picture of a cow saying something provided
>   by
>          the  user.   If run with no arguments, it accepts standard input, word-
>          wraps the message given at about 40 columns, and prints the cow  saying
>          the given message on standard output.